# How to upload consumer contract to official Pact Broker

Tags: pact, pact-jvm, pact-broker

I can do this using the following pom entry:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.provider</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <pactBrokerUrl>https://akbank.pactflow.io</pactBrokerUrl>
                <pactBrokerToken>MyToken</pactBrokerToken>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

However I don't remember where I found this sample and not sure if this is the correct way because the groupid of the maven plugin ends with ".provider".

[The documentation](https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/consumer/junit#forcing-pact-files-to-be-overwritten-365) is very limited regarding to this topic. Please advise if what I'm doing is correct.

Comment: See https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-jvm/tree/master/consumer/junit

Comment: @Gael it is the same as the documentation link I provided. The only thing it says about using the broker is: "If you use Gradle, you can use the pact Gradle plugin to publish your pact files." I'm using maven and need some sample code.

Comment: Recommended way is to use Pact CLI to publish pact files I believe. Even though it's surprising there's no maven plugin to do it I admit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it is in Pact Maven + Springboot + JUnit5 workshop, under [Step 11 - Using a Pact Broker](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-workshop-Maven-Springboot-JUnit5/tree/step11#step-11---using-a-pact-broker) title.

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
          <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.provider</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
          <version>4.1.17</version>
          <configuration>
            <pactBrokerUrl>http://localhost:9292</pactBrokerUrl>
            <pactBrokerUsername>pact_workshop</pactBrokerUsername>
            <pactBrokerPassword>pact_workshop</pactBrokerPassword>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```